# issue with rxjs flow and ngrx selector

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx

Since I read this article : [Querying a Normalized State with RxJS in Angular](https://netbasal.com/querying-a-normalized-state-with-rxjs-in-angular-71ecd7ca25b4), I am merging my selectors to his way. But I have an issue with one of those..

**GOAL :**
Group a list of Objects based on a property : Object[] map to Object[][].

*Simple case:*

```js
const a = [
  {a:2, b:'d'},
  {a:2, b:'e'},
  {a:3, b:'f'},
  {a:1, b:'b'},
  {a:1, b:'c'},
];

const a$ = Rx.Observable.of(a);

a$
  .switchMap(items => Rx.Observable.from(items))
  .groupBy(item => item.a)
  .mergeMap(group => group.toArray())
  .toArray()
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.1/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

But if the source observable is provided by a ngrx selector, I don't have any results...it doesn't pass the mergeMap operator :

```js
products$: Observable<Product[]> = this._store.select(state => state.product.products);

this.products$
  .switchMap(products => Observable.from(products))
  .groupBy(product => product.productGroup.id)
  .mergeMap(group => group.toArray())
  .toArray()
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

Before with reselect, it was working :

```js
export const getProductGroups = createSelector(getProducts, (products) => {
  let productGroups: Product[][] = [];
  Observable.from(products)
    .groupBy(product => product.productGroup.id)
    .mergeMap(group => group.toArray())
    .toArray()
    .subscribe(pgs => productGroups = pgs);
  return productGroups;
});
```

**Do someone know why ?**

Comment: Why do you need the `switchMap` at the beginning? Why would you want to recreate a new observable from the content of another observable? I feel like you can just remove this line, am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `select` from the ngrx store doesn't complete. And `toArray` requires the source observable to complete before it will emit the array.

If you include a `first()` or `take(1)` in the observable composed from the store, you should see the result you are expecting.

Alternatively, you could move the `groupBy`, etc. into the `switchMap`, like this:

```
products$: Observable<Product[]> = this._store.select(state => state.product.products);

this.products$.switchMap(products => Observable
  .from(products)
  .groupBy(product => product.productGroup.id)
  .mergeMap(group => group.toArray())
  .toArray()
)
.subscribe(console.log)
```